# jira API that returns all the issue for current version

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I need to generate a release note in JIRA.
The report need to figure out current version and need to load all the issue present in the version.
I have code with me I am not able to figure out how to get current version in velocity template.
I have code below.

```
       #macro (getReleaseNoteComment $issue $customFieldManager)
            #set ($customFields = $customFieldManager.getCustomFi

    eldObjects($issue.project.getLong("id"), $issue.issueType.getString("id")))
        #foreach($customField in $customFields)
            #if($customField.name.equals("release notes comments"))
                #if($customField.getValue($issue)) - Release Comment: $textUtils.htmlEncode($customField.getValue($issue))#end
            #end
        #end
    #end

    <title>$action.getText('release.notes.text.title', $project, $version) </title>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>

                #foreach ($issueType in $issueTypes)
                    #if($issueType.issues.size() > 0 && $issueType.equals("Epic"))
                        <h2>$textUtils.htmlEncode($issueType.name)</h2>
                        <ul>
                            #foreach ($issue in $issueType.issues)
                                <li>[<a xhref='$!appProps.getString("jira.baseurl")/browse/$issue.key'>$issue.key</a>] -
                                    $textUtils.htmlEncode($issue.summary)#getReleaseNoteComment($issue $customFieldManager)</li>
                            #end
                        </ul>
                    #end
                #end
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

This code will list out all the issue with type Epic but I need to list out only those issues who lies in current version.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of the JIRA REST API for the Confluence project and fixVersion = 5.0

`https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%20=%20CONF%20AND%20fixVersion%20=%20%225.0%22`

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but I am not looking for REST API solution. I want to edit release notes vm only that is present in jira war.